# Error C4716 in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures

```
<code>
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H


template <class T>
class Vector
{
public:

    Vector();

    ~Vector();

    void add(T element);

    int size() const;

    T get(int i) const;

    void set(int i, T element);

    bool contains(T element);

    Vector<T>& operator=(const Vector<T> &rhs);

private:

    int numElements;

    int capacity;

    T *elements;

    void expand();
};

template <class T>
Vector<T>::Vector()
{
    numElements = 0;
    capacity = 10;
    elements = new T[capacity];
}

template <class T>
Vector<T>::~Vector()
{
    delete[] elements;
}

template <class T>
void Vector<T>::add(T element)
{
    if (numElements >= capacity)
    {
        expand();
    }

    elements[numElements] = element;
    numElements++;
}

template <class T>
int Vector<T>::size() const
{
    return numElements;
}

template <class T>
T Vector<T>::get(int i) const
{
    return elements[i];
}

template <class T>
void Vector<T>::set(int i, T element)
{
    elements[i] = element;
}

template <class T>
void Vector<T>::expand()
{
    T *tempElements = new T[capacity * 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
    {
        tempElements[i] = elements[i];
    }

    delete[] elements;
    elements = tempElements;
    capacity *= 2;
}

template <class T>
bool Vector<T>::contains(T element)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++)
    {
        if (elements[i] == element)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

template <class T>
Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator=(const Vector<T> &rhs)
{
    delete[] elements;
    numElements = rhs.size();
    capacity = numElements * 2;
    elements = new T[capacity];
    for(int i = 0; i < numElements; i++)
      elements[i] = rhs.get(i);


}

#endif
</code>
```

I'm quite new to C++ and have an assignment about data structures and abstraction. I've got a few CPP and header file in the assignment which works fine except for this one. When i compile, it says "Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C4716   'Vector::operator=': must return a value  "

Comment: Read the error message again, and then check your `operator=` function. Does it return anything? I mean, actually use the `return` statement?

Comment: Which part of "Vector::operator= must return a value" you didn't understand?|

Answer (score 1):

the `Vector<T>::operator=()` is not returning anywhere and it must.

This allows for such syntax:

`a = b = c;`

So just put

```
return (*this);
```

at the end of the method.

Comment: Ah. I know I need to return something. But not sure what. Thanks alot